# What does "shouting scorn" mean?

Tags: expressions

What does "shouting scorn" mean in:

> 86 years before Boris Yeltsin  stood on a tank in Moscow in 1991, **shouting scorn** for a coup attempt, Russians marched to the Winter Palace  to present petitions to the Tsar.

What I understand is something like this:

> Russians marched to the Winter Palace to give petitions to the Tsar. 86 years after that, in 1991; Boris Yeltsin shouted "I feel contempt for any attempt to change the government" while he was standing on a tank.

Comment: Not quite "for **any** attempt to change the government," but "for a violent change to, or sudden upheaval in, the government." A _coup_ is a very specific kind of change; NOAD reads: _a sudden, violent, and illegal seizure of power_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got it about right.  There's no meaning other than the dictionary definition for the two words (ie, 'shouting scorn' is not a phrase/cliche in its own right).

Mr Yeltsin is scornful about the coup attempt, and he is shouting to let everyone know of his scorn.

I would add "by coup" to your sentence of what Mr Yeltsin is shouting.  A change of government by ordinary means probably wouldn't make him scornful.

Comment: I would have said that whereas *shouting scorn* is just about credible (I'd prefer *shouting **scornfully*** in most contexts), I can't really get my head around *shouting scorn **for** [something]*. But I've just checked Google Books, in which the *only* instance of this form is [Shouting scorn for the timid lawmen](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Shouting+scorn+for+the+timid+lawmen%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). It's from [Robert M. Utley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_M._Utley), so maybe I'd better not dismiss it as "ungrammatical". But I don't like it one little bit.

Answer (score 0):

"To shout scorn" is to shout "scornful" **words.**

Answer (score 0):

There is an expression in British English (maybe others) which is to "pour scorn" on something. President Yeltsin could have poured scorn on the coup attempt.